# Pandas scatterplot with coloring using a string

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot x and y using a scatterplot, and z as colors.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1,2 ,3],
    "y": [4, 5, 6],
    "z": ["A", "B", "C"],
})

df.plot(
    x="x",
    y="y",
    kind="scatter",
    c="z",
)
```

How can I do this using pandas plotting functionality?

This is throwing:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not ['A' 'B' 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

To plot the scatterplot with different colors based on the categorical variable `'z'`, you can map each unique value of `'z'` to a specific color using a dictionary, and then pass the mapped colors as the `'c'` argument:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": [4, 5, 6],
    "z": ["A", "B", "C"],
})

color_map = {"A": "red", "B": "green", "C": "blue"}

df.plot(
    x="x",
    y="y",
    kind="scatter",
    c=df['z'].map(color_map),
    colormap='viridis',
)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply put some colors in `'z'`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1,2 ,3],
    "y": [4, 5, 6],
    "z": ["red", "blue", "green"],
})

df.plot(
    x="x",
    y="y",
    kind="scatter",
    c="z",
)
```

[image]